# className on Drawer component doesnt work

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react and material-ui and I have come across an issue, I want to define some css behavior for the drawer component, and I have read that it is quite simple, that all I have to do is use the className property, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here is my css:

```
.drawer {
    width: 200px
}

.drawer:hover {
    background-color: black
}
```

Here is my usage of the drawer:

```
<Drawer open={this.state.isLeftNavOpen}
                             docked={false}
                             className='drawer'
                             onRequestChange={this.changeNavState}>
                        <MenuItem primaryText='Men'
                                  onTouchTap={() => browserHistory.push({pathname: '/products', query: {category: MEN}})}/>
                        <MenuItem primaryText='Women'
                                  onTouchTap={() => browserHistory.push({pathname: '/products', query: {category: WOMEN}})}/>
                        <MenuItem primaryText='Kids'
                                  onTouchTap={() => browserHistory.push({pathname: '/products', query: {category: KIDS}})}/>
                    </Drawer>
```

I tried wrapping the Drawer with div but still no success.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: see here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2310, 
you may need to pass in your styles inline..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library does seem to be adding the className, but this issue you are seeing seems to be a consequence of `material-ui` setting styles directly on the element, which take priority over those on the class you've added. There are a couple of options until the library makes some changes/fixes, such as:

1) set the width and styles inline with the `style` and/or `width` [properties](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer): ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DirectCtrl/6knx4bsc/1/))

```js
<Drawer open={this.state.isLeftNavOpen}
    docked={false}
    width={200}
    style={{'background-color': 'black'}}
    className='drawer'>
```

Unfortunately this approach doesn't allow for `:hover` styling though, and their current inline styling solution is likely to be changed in the near future (see [issue 1951](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1951) and those that follow it). That means that your only real solution at the moment to this specific problem is to:

2) mark the styles in the css as `!important` to override those set on the element by the library: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DirectCtrl/6knx4bsc/))

```css
.drawer {
    width: 200px !important;
}

.drawer:hover {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

You can also use a combination of the two, passing the width as a prop and only having the hover background style be `!important`.

(Using LeftNav (the older version of Drawer) in the fiddles because it's in the easiest-to-consume package I could find at time of writing for `material-ui`, found it on [this comment](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/4342#issuecomment-221972953)).

Comment: I just read that they are going to come up with a better solution regarding styles in the components as it mentioned here : https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4066
And it will get into the next version (0.16.0), but in the meantime, what can I do? I tried using !important but it didn't work, it didn't make any change

Comment: Using the className prop with `!important` in CSS _should_ work, it seemed to work in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DirectCtrl/6knx4bsc/). Can you provide a similar example with your code running, maybe it's something more specific to your implementation?

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me before, but now it does, except animations.
I tried the following example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6knx4bsc/3/ and the animation doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to use animations without `!important`, which is fine since there isn't an animation on this element. See https://jsfiddle.net/DirectCtrl/6knx4bsc/6/ . For this simple case you could also use transitions https://jsfiddle.net/DirectCtrl/6knx4bsc/4/